How to set TabLayout under the ViewPager?
I have TabLayout and ViewPager2 in LinearLayout:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_tabLayout"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>

It works correctly but I need TabLayout under the ViewPager. If I swap them, TabLayout doesnt display (ViewPager is visible and works correctly). How to set TabLayout under the ViewPager?
I tried
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_tabLayout"/>


</LinearLayout>

In this case only ViewPager is visible

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/main_tabLayout"
    />

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/main_tabLayout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    /> 
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Try with this layout. Hopefully, it will work.
